# How To Get Carousel To Loop

Tags: javascript, css, shopify, carousel, repeat

I am working on editting my Shopify theme's theme.js file to change the default nature of an image carousel. I want to have the buttons that control the carousel to *loop* the beginning and end when going backwards/forwards. Below is the code for the carousel and I'm having a hard time making sense of it. Any help with adding a statement that checks if it's at cc-start or cc-end to offset it to the right spot would be appreciated!

```
// Initialises Featured Collection(s) carousels
  theme.carousels = {
    init: () => {
      var _this = this;

      _this.updateArrows = (carousel) => {
        var section = $(carousel).closest('.section, .cc-carousel-section')[0];

        if (carousel.scrollLeft < 15) {
          section.classList.add('cc-start');
        } else {
          section.classList.remove('cc-start');
        }

        if (carousel.scrollLeft + carousel.clientWidth > carousel.scrollWidth - 15) {
          section.classList.add('cc-end');
        } else {
          section.classList.remove('cc-end');
          section.classList.add('cc-carousel-scrolling');
        }
      };

      _this.initArrows = () => {
        var carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".cc-carousel");
        carousels.forEach((carousel) => {
          var $sectionContainer = $(carousel).closest('.section, .cc-carousel-section');
          var $carouselNext = $sectionContainer.find('.cc-carousel--next');
          var $carouselPrevious = $sectionContainer.find('.cc-carousel--previous');

          $carouselNext.addClass('cc-initialized');
          $carouselPrevious.addClass('cc-initialized');

          if ($carouselNext.length && $carouselPrevious.length) {
            $carouselNext.on('click.cc-carousel', function (evt) {
              evt.preventDefault();

              //Get the left hand edge of the next card out of view
              var nextLeftOffset = -1;
              var carouselOffsetLeft = $(this).closest('.section, .cc-carousel-section').find('.cc-carousel').offset().left;

              $(carousel).find('.column').each(function () {
                var offsetLeft = parseInt($(this).offset().left - carouselOffsetLeft);
                if (offsetLeft > carousel.scrollLeft + carousel.clientWidth - 20 && nextLeftOffset === -1) {
                  nextLeftOffset = offsetLeft;
                }
              });

              if (nextLeftOffset === -1) {
                nextLeftOffset = carousel.scrollLeft + carousel.clientWidth;
              }

              _this.scrollLeft(carousel, nextLeftOffset);
            });

            $carouselPrevious.on('click.cc-carousel', function (evt) {
              evt.preventDefault();

              //Get the left hand edge of the next card out of view
              var nextLeftOffset = -1;

              if (theme.viewport.isXs()) {
                var carouselOffsetLeft = $(this).closest('.section, .cc-carousel-section').find('.cc-carousel').offset().left;
                var prevLeftOffsets = {};

                $(carousel).find('.column').each(function (index) {
                  var offsetLeft = parseInt($(this).offset().left - carouselOffsetLeft);
                  if (offsetLeft >= 0 && nextLeftOffset === -1) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('min-cols-2') && prevLeftOffsets[index - 2]) {
                      nextLeftOffset = carousel.scrollLeft + prevLeftOffsets[index - 2];
                    } else {
                      nextLeftOffset = carousel.scrollLeft + prevLeftOffsets[index - 1];
                    }
                  }

                  prevLeftOffsets[index] = offsetLeft;
                });
              }

              if (nextLeftOffset === -1) {
                nextLeftOffset = carousel.scrollLeft - carousel.clientWidth;
              }

              _this.scrollLeft(carousel, nextLeftOffset);
            });
          }

          _this.updateArrows(carousel);
        });
      };

      _this.scrollLeft = (carousel, left) => {
        carousel.classList.add('cc-carousel--smooth-scroll');
        carousel.scrollLeft = left;

        setTimeout(() => {
          _this.updateArrows(carousel);
          carousel.classList.remove('cc-carousel--smooth-scroll');
        }, 1000); // unsure about this number
      };

      _this.initMobileCarousels = () => {
        if (theme.viewport.isXs()) {
          var uninitializedMobCarousels = document.querySelectorAll(".cc-carousel-mobile:not(.cc-carousel)");
          uninitializedMobCarousels.forEach((carousel) => {
            carousel.classList.add('cc-carousel');
            var $sectionContainer = $(carousel).closest('.section, .cc-carousel-section');
            $sectionContainer.find('.cc-carousel--next').addClass('cc-initialized');
            $sectionContainer.find('.cc-carousel--previous').addClass('cc-initialized');
            $sectionContainer.addClass('cc-is-carousel');
          });
        } else {
          var initializedMobCarousels = document.querySelectorAll(".cc-carousel-mobile.cc-carousel");
          initializedMobCarousels.forEach((carousel) => {
            carousel.classList.remove('cc-carousel');
            var $sectionContainer = $(carousel).closest('.section, .cc-carousel-section');
            $sectionContainer.find('.cc-carousel--next').removeClass('cc-initialized');
            $sectionContainer.find('.cc-carousel--previous').removeClass('cc-initialized');
            $sectionContainer.removeClass('cc-is-carousel');
          });
        }
      };

      _this.initCarousels = () => {
        var carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".cc-carousel");

        if (carousels.length) {
          //Init click to drag on desktop browsers (except for Safari)
          if (theme.viewport.isSm() && !theme.browser.isSafari()) {
            carousels.forEach((carousel) => {
              var isDown = false,startX,scrollLeft;

              if (!carousel.classList.contains('cc-initialized')) {
                carousel.classList.add('cc-initialized');

                carousel.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
                  isDown = true;
                  startX = e.pageX - carousel.offsetLeft;
                  scrollLeft = carousel.scrollLeft;
                });

                carousel.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
                  isDown = false;
                });

                carousel.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
                  isDown = false;
                  _this.updateArrows(carousel);
                });

                carousel.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
                  if (!isDown) return;
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var x = e.pageX - carousel.offsetLeft;
                  var walk = x - startX;
                  carousel.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
                  _this.updateArrows(carousel);
                });
              }
            });
          } else {
            carousels.forEach((carousel) => {
              //Update arrows on touch end
              carousel.addEventListener("touchend", () => {
                _this.updateArrows(carousel);
              });

              //Update arrows on scroll end
              var timer;
              carousel.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
                clearTimeout(timer);

                timer = setTimeout(() => {
                  _this.updateArrows(carousel);
                }, 300);
              }, { passive: true });
            });
          }

          //Init left/right buttons
          _this.initArrows();
        }
      };

      if (document.querySelectorAll(".cc-carousel-mobile").length) {
        $(window).off('debouncedresizewidth.cc-carousel').on('debouncedresizewidth.cc-carousel', _this.initMobileCarousels);
        _this.initMobileCarousels();
      }

      _this.initCarousels();
    },
    destroy: () => {
      var carousels = document.querySelector(".cc-carousel");
      if (carousels && carousels.length) {
        carousels.forEach((carousel) => {
          carousel.removeEventListener('mousedown').
          removeEventListener('mouseleave').
          removeEventListener('mouseup').
          removeEventListener('mousemove').
          classList.remove('cc-initialized');

          var $sectionContainer = $(carousel).closest('.section, .cc-carousel-section');
          $sectionContainer.find('.cc-carousel--previous').removeClass('cc-initialized');
          $sectionContainer.find('.cc-carousel--next').removeClass('cc-initialized');
        });
      }
      $(window).off('.cc-carousel');
    } };

  ;
```

Have tried to use Offset to even slide off page but to no avail.

Comment: Why don't you use already made solutions like EmblaCarousel?

Comment: Because there is an already baked-in solution on Shopify with a front-end UI schema made for replacing the products in the carousel easier. Which I don't need but my coworkers that are in Marketing, Sales Management, Design, etc. all use it. We replace the products in the carousel weekly and they wouldn't be able to use EmblaCarousel.

Comment: I don't think we understand each other. The content editor interacts with Theme Customizer, not the code. Customization is possible because of liquid template language. EmblaCarousel is just a javascript library that has nothing to do with theme customizer. Those two do not conflict with each other. In fact, they can play nice together. In the end, it's up to you. I'm just saying it would be much easier for you to use any library with all features that you need instead of reinventing the wheel.